# Elements move when exporting to pdf in Indesign cs5

Tags: master-pages, flash-cs5, adobe-indesign

When I export a document, elements from the master page moves and duplicates themselves on the pdf. I have searched for hidden objects with no result. I have also made a new layer and new master pages.

I have found a similar problem but that solution didn´t work.
link:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1231200?tstart=0

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Indesign CC
Masterpage elements that were 'released' and moved on regular pages, reappeared as duplicates in the pdf on their original masterpage location.
The elements in question were groups.
Ungrouping solved the problem.
HTH
Willem van den Goorbergh